# Creating a todo list in javascript only

Tags: javascript

I have a problem here.I need to create a todo list with the following specifications:
It should have list,form and local storage components as described below.
The list component's responsibilities are to:

> Attach to the list element in the HTML.
>
> Maintain the active todo list in the running web app.
>
> Draw the list of todos.
>
> Redraw the list when a new item is added or removed.
>
> Interact with the storage service to retrieve the list of todo items from the browser's local storage on launch and save the list of todos to the browser's local storage whenever it changes.

The form component's responsibilities are to:

> Attach to the list-form element in the HTML.
>
> Draw the form, input, and submit button.
>
> Add the new item to the todo list when the form is submited by interacting with the list component.
>
> Clearing the input after the new todo item has been added allowing for a new item to be entered.

The local storage component's responsibilities are to:

> Provide methods that store and retrieve the list of todos in the browser's local storage.
>   I have tired the following code:

```
function get_todos() {
    var todos = new Array;
    var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
    if (todos_str !== null) {
        todos = JSON.parse(todos_str); 
    }
    return todos;
}

//local storage

function add() {
    var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

    var todos = get_todos();
    todos.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

    show();

    return false;
}

function remove() {
    var id = this.getAttribute('id');
    var todos = get_todos();
    todos.splice(id, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

    show();

    return false;
}
//local storage
function show() {
    var todos = get_todos();

    var html = '<ul>';
    for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
        html += '<li>' + todos[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">x</button></li>';
    };
    html += '</ul>';

    document.getElementById('k').innerHTML = html;
    //document.getElementsByTagName("list");

    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
    };
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
show();
```

Please I need your assistance.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem? Is your code throwing an error? We can only help if you tell us *exactly* what you expect your code to do and what it's currently doing. No one is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: After deriving the markup from the code (an input with the id "task", a link or button with the id "add", and some kind of container with the id "k") and throwing it all together, it works without any errors or issues. :|

Comment: the code is not throwing any error.it is working correctly but I have not met my objectives.I need asssistance in assigning an ID to a button created by javascript.

Comment: I have created a button using var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);. how do i give it an id?

Comment: @code Check out [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Comment: `btn.id = 'add'`.  Seriously dude.  Don't you have a professor you can ask this or a book that goes over it (in probably the first chapter)? Also nowhere in your question did you mention anything about needing help creating a button or assigning it an id.